# Android intent-filter path pattern

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to make intent-filter which can detect urls like this one:

> http://www.example.com/?p=12345

I tried with this code:

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="http"
                android:host="www.example.com"
                android:pathPattern="/\\?p=.*"/>

        </intent-filter>
```

But it doesn't work. Can anybody help?

Comment: no, device just don't try to open url with my app

Comment: You can't filter on query parameters, only the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="www.example.com"
                android:pathPattern="/*"
                android:scheme="http" />
            <data
                android:host="www.example.com"
                android:pathPattern="/.*/"
                android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
```